# Unable to read data from ADLS gen 2 in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have followed this Microsoft Documentation to connect to my gen2 storage account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/connect/storage/tutorial-azure-storage

and used this to authenticate according to step 6:

```
service_credential = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>",key="<service-credential-key>")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

Now when I am running this:

```
df = spark.read.csv("abfss://<filepath>")
```

I am getting this error:
abfss://filepath has invalid authority.

I have double checked :

1. tenant id of the SP
2. client id of the SP
3. secret scope name created according to the above mentioned documentation
4. The role of the service principal in the container is "Storage Blob data Contributor"

File Service properties of my storage account:

Large file share Disabled

Identity-based access Not configured

Default share-level permissions Disabled

Soft delete Enabled (7 days)

Share capacity 5 TiB

Comment: Are you missing double quotes for the client secret?
`spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<service_credential>")`

Comment: No. Accroding to the documentation, it is : spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)

Comment: Sorry, just rewatched my conf, you're right. your filepath is like: "abfss://<container_name>@<sa_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/" ?

Comment: yeah. Do you know if the key vault, storage account and the databricks have to be under the same RG? In my case, storage account is under one RG, and the key vault and data bricks under one RG.

Comment: I don't think so beacause you can also connect from aws with the same conf:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html Have you tried without using the secret scope and putting all credentials/ids hardcoded?
I see no flaws in your conf

Comment: Yes. For some reason, SP is not working properly. Then I tried creating a scope for the storage account access key and it worked. SP has proper access to the container but I am not sure what the issue was. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Scope for SP didn't work even though the SP had "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role. So I tried creating a scope for my container's access key and it worked without any issues. Not sure exactly what the issue was though with the SP. I used this:

```
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.<container>.blob.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get("scope-name", "secret-name"))

df = spark.read.csv(f"wasbs://container-name@sa_name.blob.core.windows.net/filepath")
```